# How to get full path of StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm creating a `StreamWriter` using a relative path. But the file doesn't appear. To troubleshoot, I want to check that the full path is what I'm expecting. So having a `StreamWriter` instance, how can I get the full path of the file it's going to write to?

```
string fileName = "relative/path.txt"
StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter(fileName);
// What is the full path of 'sw'?
```

Comment: Have you considered that when you run your application inside visual studio the current directory is bin/debug or bin/release ?

Comment: @Steve yes i'm looking for files in bin/debug/release directory.... files are not there and that's why I want to obtain full path programatically. To compare if i'm searching in the right dir

Comment: ok I've used "search files" feature of Windows and finally found where my files are. question can be closed or can be left opened so someone can answer it...

Comment: @javapowered If this file can be closed, that you can do this on yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the full path from a relative path, use the [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) method.

For example:

```
string fileName = "relative/path.txt";
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
```

Answer (score 65):

In my version of the framework, this seems to work:

```
string fullPath = ((FileStream)(streamWriter.BaseStream)).Name;
```

(Found by debugging.)

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer that suits the question-title. Did you mean found by `introspection`...?

Answer (score 1):

Might be the directory 'relative' not exists. Either create it manually. Or create it programmatically as below

```
string fileName = @"relative\path.txt";
fileName = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));

StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter(fileName, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim fs As FileStream = CType(sw.BaseStream, FileStream)
Dim fi As New FileInfo(fs.Name)
Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be better as a comment to @Jeppe Stiehl Nielsen's reply, but I can't add comments:
In VB.Net, this becomes:

`Dim fullPath As String = CType(streamWriter.BaseStream, FileStream).Name`

I'm not sure why the `CType` is needed, and only for this property while all other properties do not, but it's needed.

Comment: Because `CType` casts an object's type. `BaseStream` is a `Stream`. `FileStream` inherits that base class, but in this case we're sure that the base stream is actually a file stream because that's what the path points to. Ie. the path is not a stream to a FTP connection for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using nullable types and safe casting (`as` doesn't throw exceptions):

```cs
_logger.LogInformation("Wrote file at {0}", (streamWriter.BaseStream as FileStream)?.Name);
```

`?` only accesses the property if the result of the expression on the left is not `null`, otherwise it returns (evaluates to) `null` (it's like it's equivalent to `E is T ? (T)(E) : (T)null`).

If you wanted, you could check the cast result for `null` like this:

```cs
var fs = streamWriter.BaseStream as FileStream;

if (fs != null)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Wrote file at {0}", fs.Name);
}
```

But that's more code than you need. The more modern way to write the above example with C# 7+ is to use the `is` operator:

```cs
if (streamWriter.BaseStream is FileStream fs)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Wrote report file at {0}", fs.Name);
}
```

This has the added benefit that the log call doesn't happen at all, if the cast could not be performed, because actually `fs` is never `null` when using `is`. The entire `is` expression evaluates to either true or false, but never `null`.

Answer (score -2):

```
  var fstream = sw.BaseStream as System.IO.FileStream;
  if (fstream != null)
    Console.WriteLine(GetAbsolutePathByHandle(fstream.SafeFileHandle));


[DllImport("ntdll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int NtQueryObject(SafeFileHandle handle, int objectInformationClass, IntPtr buffer,  int StructSize, out int returnLength);

static string GetAbsolutePathByHandle(SafeFileHandle handle)
{
  var size = 1024;
  var buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);
  try
  {
    int retSize;
    var res = NtQueryObject(handle, 1, buffer, size, out retSize);
    if (res == -1073741820)
    {
      Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer);
      size = retSize;
      Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);
      res = NtQueryObject(handle, 1, buffer, size, out retSize);
    }
    if (res != 0)
      throw new Exception(res.ToString());
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 4 + (Environment.Is64BitProcess ? 12 : 4); i < retSize - 2; i += 2)
    {
      builder.Append((char)Marshal.ReadInt16(buffer, i));
    }
    return builder.ToString();
  }
  finally
  {
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume2\bla-bla\relative\path.txt
```